# Best way to config gunicorn and nginx with django?

Tags: django, nginx, heroku, gunicorn

I am trying to deploy django with gunicorn and nginx on heroku, and i'm kinda confused with the way to config gunicorn and nginx, when i searched through internet, they usually create gunicorn.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

and gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=sammy
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/sammy/myprojectdir
ExecStart=/home/sammy/myprojectdir/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          myproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

but when i go to gunicorn docs : https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html. nginx has a config file like this

```
worker_processes 1;

user nobody nogroup;
# 'user nobody nobody;' for systems with 'nobody' as a group instead
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 1024; # increase if you have lots of clients
  accept_mutex off; # set to 'on' if nginx worker_processes > 1
  # 'use epoll;' to enable for Linux 2.6+
  # 'use kqueue;' to enable for FreeBSD, OSX
}

http {
  include mime.types;
  # fallback in case we can't determine a type
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined;
  sendfile on;

  upstream app_server {
    # fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
    # to return a good HTTP response

    # for UNIX domain socket setups
    server unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;

    # for a TCP configuration
    # server 192.168.0.7:8000 fail_timeout=0;
  }

  server {
    # if no Host match, close the connection to prevent host spoofing
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 444;
  }

  server {
    # use 'listen 80 deferred;' for Linux
    # use 'listen 80 accept_filter=httpready;' for FreeBSD
    listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    # set the correct host(s) for your site
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # path for static files
    root /path/to/app/current/public;

    location / {
      # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
      try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      # we don't want nginx trying to do something clever with
      # redirects, we set the Host: header above already.
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
      root /path/to/app/current/public;
    }
  }
}
```

So i wonder what the different between these and which is the best way to setup gunicorn, nginx.
Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to use Nginx on Heroku? It's common to simply run Gunicorn since Heroku provides its own HTTP routing system.

Comment: cuz Heroku is not my final target, I want to deploy on Heroku first, then on the private server, so I wonder about the way to configure these things

Comment: Okay, well, Heroku is not a private server. It works completely differently. If you're planning to deploy to a VPS, I suggest you just... deploy to a VPS. Trying to get Nginx running on Heroku isn't going to be worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

you can try following steps to deploy django project using nginx, supervisor and gunicron

1- Create new gunicorn script in /myprojectenv/bin/script name e.g gunicorn_start

```
#!/bin/bash
NAME="myproject"
DJANGODIR=/home/sammy/myprojectdir/myproject
SOCKFILE=/home/sammy/myprojectdir/myproject/run/proj_name.sock
USER=sammy
GROUP=www-data
NUM_WORKERS=3
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=myproject.wsgi
echo "Starting $NAME as whoami"
cd $DJANGODIR
source ../myprojectenv/bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR
exec ../myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application 
--name $NAME 
--workers $NUM_WORKERS 
--user=$USER --group=$GROUP 
--bind=unix:$SOCKFILE 
--log-level=debug 
--log-file=-
```

2- Install supervisorctl
pip or yum install supervisor

3- Create conf file under /etc/supervisor.d

Example config file

```
[program:myproject]
directory=/home/sammy/myprojectdir/myproject
command=/home/sammy/myprojectdir/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn_start --workers 3 --bind uxix:/home/sammy/myprojectdir/myproject/run/proj_name.sock myproject.wsgi:application
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/home/sammy/myprojectdir/myproject/Logs/gunicorn_supervisor.log
stdout_logfile=/home/sammy/myprojectdir/myproject/Logs/gunicorn_supervisor.log
user=sammy
group=www-data
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

4- Supervisorctl reread & supervisorctl update

5- nano /etc/nginx/site-available/app.conf

6- ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/app.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
7- systemctl restart nginx

**Please change folder names and path according to your project.**

Comment: tks but i'm not using supervisor for now